# Python cannot find mongoengine module

Tags: linux, virtualenv, python-2.x, mongoengine, archlinux

I've been trying to set up my first bottle server. I've started a virtualenv, installed bottle and mongoengine using pip. The problem is that even then I get the following error when I run the bottleApp.py to start the server

> No module named mongoengine

in the line where I do

```
from mongoengine import *
```

I also found that my $PYTHONPATH has not been set in the virtualenv. Should I set $PYTHONPATH and $PATH manually to solve my issue ?

I am running on ArchLinux and the current version of arch now installs python 3.x by default I had installed python2 and python2-pip and installed bottle and mongoengine using pip2. Is it any dependency issue or a conflict that is causing this error ?

I am confused between the two. Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, may be problems. Can try rebuilt virtual enviroment with python version you want.

For creating your virtualenv instance to specify the Python 2.7:

> virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7

After, you can install packages an appropriate way

`pip install name_packege`

or

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: yeah i was doing pip2 install and that was causing the problem

Answer (score 5):

Try the following command on terminal of Ububtu(Linux):

```
$pip install mongoengine
```

Then run the server again and the problem will be solved.

Comment: I'm using Anaconda Jupyter Notebook. To install it in that terminal, I had to use "pip install mongoengine" instead because $pip throws an error. Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check whether the package is actually installed?

In the virtualenv, could you try:

```
pip freeze | grep mongoengine
```